# Does connecting Mist/Ethereum Wallet to parity update chaindata for geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, parity

I cannot get Mist or rather geth to sync the last few blocks.  It's been days now and all recommendations and the try, try again approach that worked in the past continue to fail.  So, I'm trying parity.  I see that parity can somehow work with geth and the Mist browser can then connect to that.   I don't fully understand all that, but I think it has something to do with IPC.  **What I really want to know, is when parity is run in such a way to work with geth, does the geth chaindata get updated or parity chaindata?**  What *I want to avoid is having two very large chunks of data, two separate chains to keep in sync with the network*, yet at the same time still be able to use Mist (nice interface for quickly purchasing coins, and ability to experiment with Swarm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parity only updates its own data. When parity is running in 'geth' mode it will be like a translator it will understand geth commands but it will not create a second copy of the blockchain data.